# How to add a Json Object to a Json Array?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley

```
println(foodIds)
        val userId = itemsInCart[0].userId
        val restaurantId = itemsInCart[0].restaurantId
        val foodIdsJsonArray = JSONArray()   // "food" is a JsonArray
        val foodJsonObject = JSONObject()   // for storing food_item_id
        for( i in 0 until foodIds.size)
        {
            foodJsonObject.put("food_item_id",foodIds.get(i))
            println(foodJsonObject)
            foodIdsJsonArray.put(foodJsonObject)
        }
        println(foodIdsJsonArray)
```

I want to create a JsonArray with the objects {"food_item_id":41,"food_item_id":40}
But the id 41 is repeated as seen from the output. Please help.
The output:

```
I/System.out: [40, 41]
I/System.out: {"food_item_id":"40"}
I/System.out: {"food_item_id":"41"}
I/System.out: [{"food_item_id":"41"},{"food_item_id":"41"}]
```

Comment: I think your problem is due to modifying the foodJsonObject that you have created before the loop. you need to create your jsonObject inside the loop so that there is a new object for each item.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Thank you so much!